# How to execute the failed test in TestNG using retry analyzer with same data?

Tags: java, testng

I need sample code for Retry analyzer for execute failed test cases in testNG.

Answer (score 1):

You need to implement `IRetryAnalyzer` interface and override its method `retry`, then you need to add it as a `@Test` parameter `@Test(retryAnalyzer = RetryAnalyzerImpl.class)`. 
But pay attention that there is only one instance of your `RetryAnalyzer` and if you run your tests in parallel there will be some difficulties. Look at [this](https://www.toolsqa.com/selenium-webdriver/implement-iretryanalyzer-to-retry-failed-test-in-testng-framework/) example